# What happens with the received email when email forwarding is active in Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

If I have forwarding activated in Gmail, the email will show *only* in the account to which is forwarded? Or it will show both in the one to which is sent and in the one to which is forwarded?

Comment: It depends on your settings- you can have it either way.

Answer (score 3):

When you set up forwarding in Gmail, you have four options:

- keep Gmail's copy in the inbox
- mark Gmail's copy as read
- archive Gmail's copy
- delete Gmail's copy

[image: Gmail fowarding settings]